# How to implement client pull javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am working on an application, where I have one page whose partial content need updating in a interval. I am thinking using JavaScript setInterval to do this task, but I have not used this method before, so how can I start setinterval when that specific page is loaded and stop setinterval before the page unloaded.

by the way, if you know of any better way to do this kind of task, please be kind to share with me. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a function

```
function myFunction() {
    ...
}
```

To run it every `n` milliseconds, use

```
setInterval(myFunction, n);
```

You won't need to stop the interval yourself when the page is 'unloaded' or traversed away from; this is done automatically. If, however, you wish to stop  it at any other time, then save the return value of `setInterval` when you use it, like this:

```
var timer_id = setInterval(myFunction, n);
```

and use this to stop the interval timer:

```
clearInterval(timer_id);
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, I use setInterval(myFunction, n); in myfunction I put alert('test'), but the it still popup 'test' when I navigate to another page. any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, when you say that you 'navigate to another page'?

Comment: go from one page to another page. you know that I only need the updating for one specific page.

Comment: It doesn't do what you are saying for me; when I go to another page, the timer stops because the page has been destroyed.

Comment: wait,,,i think it is because I use the same js file for all pages, that is why I can not stop it.

Comment: do you know how I can stop the timer in this case? thanks for help.

Comment: You may need to use information from the `location` object to determine which page you are on, and whether or not it is appropriate to start the timer.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial should help you: [How To Check For New Tweets From a User](http://webhole.net/2010/05/10/how-to-check-for-new-tweets-from-a-user/)

Answer (score -1):

To start the timer you just call setInterval as the page loads.  You don't need to stop the timer as it will stop automatically when the page is unloaded.

Here is an example copied from the w3schools website which also shows how to manually stop the timer if necessary via clearInterval:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="clock" />
<script language=javascript>
var int=self.setInterval("clock()",1000);
function clock()
  {
  var d=new Date();
  var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("clock").value=t;
  }
</script>
</form>
<button onclick="int=window.clearInterval(int)">Stop</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is a very poor code example for many reasons (no doctype, using self-close in HTML, passing a string to `setInterval`, using a reserved keyword, using the `language` attribute, and using inline event handlers). Please do not refer to w3schools.com. For more information, see http://w3fools.com/